# Can I use a loan for something other than what I said I'd use it for?

Tags: united-kingdom, banking, solicitor, borrowing

I'd like to purchase some grazing land. I'm half way there with the funds and thought of covering the remaining cost with a loan. This would be a personal loan from a UK bank and not secured against anything. However, when searching and comparing each bank they ask for the purpose of the loan, of which a land purchase is not an option. I phoned a couple banks and was told they didn't supply loans for such purposes.

So... what is to stop me from getting a loan and telling the bank it's for buying a car etc. then using the money to buy the land?

Secondary to what the bank may have to say, what would a solicitor say if I said the source of funds was from a personal loan. Would they contact the bank and check the purpose?

Comment: Say purpose is something personal - for exercising your hobbies for example. Or say you will be covering unexpected expenses. Or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

Well ... the crime of fraud and the tort of deception.

If you say you will do X and enter a contract on that basis *knowing* that you won't then that is fraud and it carries gaol time. Your bank could also revoke your contract and sue for damages.

Comment: Goal time, or Gooooooooooool time?

Comment: One is supposed to Google it. Totally different language.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gaol

Comment: What would happen if you had suffient money without the loan? Have £10k in bank, apply for £5k loan with the stated reason of "to buy a car", but actually buy land worth £5k (and maybe a car). What if you were planning to buy the car all along but only planning to buy the land if you got the loan (which you said was for a car)? What if you truthfully said you wanted to use the money to buy a car but didn't buy a car immediately and instead spent the money on urgent home repairs or frittered it on an enormous fried food collection? (This is starting to sound like a question of its own...)

Comment: FWIW, my previous comment is a genuine one, I'm not trying to pick holes.